# Appium (and desktop) unable to launch wda session since xCode13 and iOS15

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop, ios15

Since my xCode got (automatically...) updated to 13 and all my simulators moved from iOS 14.5 to 15. with the same setup / commands I'm unable to launch the WDA from both the desktop app, and the node ( selenium server grid/node setup)

The issue exists for all simulators.
I can still use real device..

(the actual ports in errors might differ, the first one is from the actual automation where it fails, the 2nd and 3rd is from the desktop app -where it still fails with the same error. the root issue is still the same on both)

The error logs I get:
In short:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8205
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Janoss-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:18e4:52:307c:8c7b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8205
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Janoss-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:18e4:52:307c:8c7b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
```

The longer error from the server:

```
[iOSSim] Got Simulator UI client PID: 11815
[iOSSim] Both Simulator with UDID 'F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A' and the UI client are currently running
[BaseDriver] Event 'simStarted' logged at 1632487969688 (14:52:49 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time))
[WebDriverAgent] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[DevCon Factory] Requesting connection for device F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A on local port 8100
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[DevCon Factory] Successfully requested the connection for F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A:8100
[XCUITest] Starting WebDriverAgent initialization with the synchronization key 'XCUITestDriver'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WebDriverAgent] WDA is not listening at 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/'
[WebDriverAgent] WDA is currently not running. There is nothing to cache
[XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 2 times with 10000ms interval
[XCUITest] These values can be customized by changing wdaStartupRetries/wdaStartupRetryInterval capabilities
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1632487969773 (14:52:49 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[WebDriverAgent] WebDriverAgent does not need a cleanup. The sources are up to date (1620631774000 >= 1620631774000)
[WebDriverAgent] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A, F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A.*XCTRunner, xctest.*F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A' for the device F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A...
[WebDriverAgent] 'pgrep -if xcodebuild.*F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[WebDriverAgent] 'pgrep -if F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A.*XCTRunner' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[WebDriverAgent] 'pgrep -if xctest.*F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[WebDriverAgent] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=15.0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' in directory '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent'
[WebDriverAgent] Output from xcodebuild will only be logged if any errors are present there. To change this, use 'showXcodeLog' desired capability
[WebDriverAgent] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
```

Then a long waiting with only the ECONNREFUSED error and finally failing:

```
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session (An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100). Retrying...
[XCUITest] UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[XCUITest]     at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:274:13)
[XCUITest]     at runMicrotasks ()
[XCUITest]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[XCUITest] Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent
[WebDriverAgent] Shutting down sub-processes
[iOSSim] Building bundle path map
[iOSSim] The simulator has '1' bundles which have 'WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner' as their 'CFBundleName':
[iOSSim]     'com.jano.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner'
[WebDriverAgent] Uninstalling WDAs: 'com.jano.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner'
[XCUITest] {}
[DevCon Factory] Releasing connections for F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A device on any port number
[DevCon Factory] Found cached connections to release: ["F5A500AB-FAA5-41A0-A009-E5A8EDB8643A:8100"]
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[IOSSimulatorLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1632488146662 (14:55:46 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[MJSONWP]     at quitAndUninstall (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:544:15)
[MJSONWP]     at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:610:11
[MJSONWP]     at wrapped (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:60:13)
[MJSONWP]     at retry (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:43:13)
[MJSONWP]     at retryInterval (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:70:10)
[MJSONWP]     at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:559:7
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 177858 ms - 388
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue,
We need to update our appkum on the computer ( should be 1.22.0 or above)

To see your version:

```
appium -v
```

To install / Update your appium:

```
npm install -g appium
```

This fixed the simulator part. to fix the appium desktop, you also have to update the desktop app, but now it's moved on as 2 separate app.

One for the server
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/

And one for the inspector https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the old appium (where the server and the inspector were combined), and with the new version, where they were taken out separately.

I solved it by adding server Capabilities:

```
serverCapabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetries", "4");
serverCapabilities.setCapability("iosInstallPause","8000" );
serverCapabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetryInterval", "20000");
```

after that, the wda session became stable

Comment: This answer resolved my problem as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I solved it by adding appium desired capabilities and I reduced the time from 120 to 60 for newCommandTimeout capabilities

my appium capabilities' last status
"newCommandTimeout": 60,
"wdaStartupRetries": 3,
"wdaStartupRetryInterval": 20000